# How show sheet loaded from xib? (MacOSx)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a xib file with only an NSPanel in it, I'm trying to show this panel as modal sheet (with `beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`). The file's owner for this xib is a controller class "MyController" which has the IBOutlet to the NSPanel.

What I am looking for is something like:

```
...
MyController *controller = [[MyController alloc] init];

[NSApp beginSheet:controller.panel modalForWindow:[NSApp mainWindow] modalDelegate:controller didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
...
```

Question:
Must MyController inherit from `NSWindowController` or `NSObject`?. I tried `NSWindowController` and `initWithWindowNibName:` but the outlet to `NSPanel` always is nil.

Thanks

Comment: NSWindowController will lazily load the XIB file when its 'window' accessor is called. If you subclass window controller, try removing your panel outlet, and use the built in window outlet. Then when you call the accessor to present the sheet the XIB will be loaded. The memory handling of the top level objects from [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"XibName" owner:self] is tricky. NSWindowController handles all of that for you. I'd recommend using it. Also, the property in the inspector that you want to be off or the window is 'Visible At Launch'.

Comment: How NSWindowCntroller know what xib to load when you access its 'window' property?

Comment: when you initialize an NSWindowController, you provide the name or path to the nib.  That's how it knows what nib to load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resolve it. You must deactivate almost all the properties of the window object (in the IB) that you are using for the sheet. I add the following method to my controller to show the sheet:

```
- (void)showInWindow:(NSWindow *)mainWindow {
    if (!panelSheet)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"XibName" owner:self];

    [NSApp beginSheet:panelSheet modalForWindow:mainWindow modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:panelSheet];   //This call blocks the execution until [NSApp stopModal] is called
    [NSApp endSheet:panelSheet];
    [panelSheet orderOut:self];
}
```

`panelSheet` is an IBOutlet to the sheet window.

Thanks Jon Hess and JWWalker for your help