# Modal session requires modal window Error for when trying to show second window in Xib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I got a Xib with two NSWindows inside and a Controller inherited from NSWindowController. The first window is connected to the window IBOutlet. The second is connected to a new IBOutlet mySecondWindow.

I then create the controller using

```
myController = [[MySheetController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MySheet"];
```

Then I call a method on this controller which shows the first window as a Sheet:

```
[NSApp beginSheet:self.window modalForWindow:mainWindow modalDelegate:self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];
```

This works as expected. But if i now run the call with my second window instead, it will give the error "Modal session requires modal window". And when i debug, i can see the mySecondWindow IBOutlet is nil.

```
[NSApp beginSheet:mySecondWindow modalForWindow:mainWindow modalDelegate:self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];
```

When i now change the window IBOutlet to my second window, it will work normally.

So what do I have to do to get the second sheet shown. Why will it only load when it's connected to the window IBOutlet? Shouldn't the initWithWindowNibName call create all windows in the Xib?

Edit: so i made a minimal example:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MyWindowController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    MyWindowController* mwc;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    mwc = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Window"];    
    
    // 1. the following works:
    [NSApp beginSheet:mwc.window modalForWindow:self.window modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];
    
    // 2. this one doesn't
    [NSApp beginSheet:mwc.mySecondWindow modalForWindow:self.window modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];
}

- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}

@end
```

MyWindowController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyWindowController : NSWindowController
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSPanel *mySecondWindow;

@end
```

MyWindowController.m:

```
#import "MyWindowController.h"

@implementation MyWindowController

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    
}

@end
```

Then i made a new Xib with a NSWindow in it and a second NSPanel. I set the class of the File's Owner to the MyWindowControlller class. Then i connected the NSWindow to the window property of the files owner and i made a new IBOutlet und connected the NSPanel to it. For both windows i deselected "Visible at Launch".

When running the first beginSheet call, all works as expected. But when i instead run the second line with the mySecondWindow it gives me a:

*** Assertion failure in -[NSApplication _commonBeginModalSessionForWindow:relativeToWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.40/AppKit.subproj/NSApplication.m:3920

Modal session requires modal window

I got a solution:

```
- (id)initWithWindowNibName:(NSString *)windowNibName
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:windowNibName];
    if (self) {
        [self window];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I need to call self.window one time, then everything works out ok. The windows will be loaded lazy when accessing the window property. That's why.

I guess there's a better way to force it to load all windows, so i can use the second window first, but well this works.

See the comments here: [How show sheet loaded from xib? (MacOSx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107227/how-show-sheet-loaded-from-xib-macosx)

Comment: I just made an experiment doing what you describe, and it works fine. Is there any other information you could share?

Comment: I included a NSLog(@"%@",mySecondWindow); before the beginSheet call and it's now working. I somehow need to access it before showing it?

Comment: No, you don't need to access it before showing it. There must be something else.

Comment: Did you enable "Title Bar" on Interface Builder for your IBOutlet window?

Comment: mySecondWindow is a local var? Who set it? Shouldn't it be self.mySecondWindow?

Comment: I have "Title Bar" enabled, but switching it off won't change anything.

Comment: @property (weak) IBOutlet NSPanel *mySecondWindow;